# Could Azog possibly have been under Sauron's influence?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In the books, I can't remember what year it was, but Sauron sent orcs and other creatures to Moria, and then a couple hundred years after, Azog declared himself king of Moria.  I think it's possible Sauron may have chosen an orc chieftain or champion to rule Moria.  Is there any evidence to support or refute this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any evidence that specifically support or refutes this. In the books, Azog was killed in 2799 of the Third Age, and Sauron had been relatively active (for a disembodied spirit of malevolence, at least) in Dol Guldur for a while by then.

I can't say whether or not Sauron personally put Azog in charge (That seems like the kind of minutiae that a god wouldn't get involved with), but Azog was almost certainly working for Sauron at this time. It seems extremely likely that Azog's killing of Thror (which kicked off the Battle of Azanulbizar in the books, rather than taking place during it as the movie shows), was motivated by Sauron's desire to possess the ring of power that he would later acquire from Thrain, Thror's son and Thorin's father.

Comment: Tale of Years for TA 2480: "Sauron begins to people Moria with his creatures".

Comment: I do think azog may have killed thror on saurons orders it would make sense in my opinion but then again why would azog declare himself king of moria if he was saurons servant?

Comment: Sauron may have been in charge of the big picture, but Azog was in charge of Moria. Azog probably called himself "king" partly to irritate the dwarves, and partly because orcs don't have a very complicated social structure. Sauron probably didn't care what Azog called himself; seeing orcs as slave creatures, he would only have cared that they served him

Comment: Also, if Azog didn't die during the war of the Dwarves and Orcs leaving the denizens of the Mines of Moria leaderless then they would have been organized enough to heed Sauron's call and would have sent forces to Mordor.  Remember that it wasn't until TA 2800 that the Orcs of the North started migrating to Mordor through Rohan.

Comment: The Tale of Years says that "Orcs from the North trouble Rohan" starting in T.A. 2800. There's no mention of it them doing so *en route* to Mordor, though. A comment in the entry for Brytta in the list of the Kings of the Mark only mentions that the Orcs, being driven from the North (presumably by the Dwarves) are seeking refuge in the White Mountains.